# FlightJs event propagation

Tags: javascript, twitter-flight

Here is a piece of index.html:

```
<div id="top">
    <div id="lvl1a">
    </div>
</div>
```

I have attachd two flightJS components to that structure.

One for top element:

```
function top() {
    this.after('initialize', function () {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Top initialized.');

        this.on('broadcastEvent', function (e, data) {
            console.log("[DEBUG] Broadcast recived: " + data.message);
        });
        this.trigger('broadcastEvent', {
            message: "This is a broadcast message."
        });
    });
}
```

And second for the lvl1a:

```
function lvl1a() {
    this.after('initialize', function () {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Lvl 1 a initialized.');

        this.on('broadcastEvent', function (e, data) {
            console.log("[DEBUG] Broadcast recived: " + data.message);
        });
    });
}
```

My output is:

```
[DEBUG] Top initialized.
[DEBUG] Broadcast recived: This is a broadcast message. 
[DEBUG] Lvl 1 a initialized.
```

Why the event isn't propagated to the children nodes? How can I make that happen ?

**EDIT:**
I figured out that those events are propagated from bottom up.
Is there any possibility to change it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Flight (jQuery actually) uses standard DOM event propagation schema - events are bubbling from child to parent.

So in order to receive notifications from all children you should put your event handler on document root element (`<html>`) or common container element like `<body>`.

Try this

```
function lvl1a() {
    this.after('initialize', function () {
        console.log('[DEBUG] Lvl 1 a initialized.');

        $(document.body).on('broadcastEvent', function (e, data) {
            console.log("[DEBUG] Broadcast recived: " + data.message);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. Is there any way to change the default propagation schema from bubbling to capturing? So to broadcast the message from the top to all children ?

Comment: Event capturing is not event broadcasting. In order to call event handlers on all elements of some container you can do something like this:
`$(container).find().triggerHandler("broadcastEvent");`
but it can be quite expensive as it will traverse all descendants of the container - `O(N)` operation.